# Transpose a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = data.frame (Gender = c ("F", "M", "M", "F"),
  cat_age = c ("] 10-15]", "] 10, 15]", "] 20 -25] ","] 55-60] "), 
  frequency = c (2, 6, 8, 7))
```

I would like to transform it like this:

```
F; M; cat_age
2; 6; ] 10, 15]
0; 8; ] 20, 25]
7; 0; ] 55, 60]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's something weird with your data.frame, if `"] 10-15]"` and `"] 10, 15]"` are supposed to be the same category, you need to make it so in the data.frame. For example:

```
df = data.frame (Gender = c ("F", "M", "M", "F"), 
cat_age = c ("] 10-15]", "] 10-15]", "] 20 -25] ","] 55-60] "), frequency = c (2, 6, 8, 7))
```

Then you can use `pivot_wider()` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)

pivot_wider(df,values_from=frequency,names_from=Gender,values_fill=0)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  cat_age          F     M
  <fct>        <dbl> <dbl>
1 "] 10-15]"       2     6
2 "] 20 -25] "     0     8
3 "] 55-60] "      7     0
```

Comment: you could `%>% select(F, M, cat_age)` if you want to re-order the columns as shown in the example ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `reshape`

```
dfout <- reshape(
  transform(df,
    cat_age = sapply(
      regmatches(cat_age, gregexpr("\\d+", cat_age)),
      function(x) paste0("]", paste0(x, collapse = ","), "]")
    )
  ),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "cat_age",
  timevar = "Gender"
)
```

which gives

```
> dfout
  cat_age frequency.F frequency.M
1 ]10,15]           2           6
3 ]20,25]          NA           8
4 ]55,60]           7          NA
```

---

If you want to replace `NA` by `0`, you can add one more line

```
replace(df,is.na(df),0)
```

such that

```
> replace(dfout,is.na(dfout),0)
  cat_age frequency.F frequency.M
1 ]10,15]           2           6
3 ]20,25]           0           8
4 ]55,60]           7           0
```